# Prevent last component of LWUIT form from losing focus when down arrow key is pressed

Tags: java-me, lwuit, lwuit-form, lwuit-textarea, lwuit-container

I have a lwuit `Form` to which I have added a `Container`. The `Container` has a `TextArea`, some `RadioButtons` and finally another `Container` which has some `Buttons`.

1)`TextArea`
2)`RadioButtons`
3)Another `Container` with some `Buttons`

Now if the focus is on my last `Container` on the `Form` and I press the 'down arrow key' the focus jumps to the first component `TextArea` .

Likewise, if the focus is on my first `Container` on the `Form` `TextArea` and I press the 'up arrow key' the focus jumps to the last component of the `Form`.

This is very annoying. How do i prevent this from happening?

So incase the focus is on the first `Container` of the `Form` `TextArea`...I want the focus to remain on `TextArea` even if the 'up arrow' key is press.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can solve that issue using the `Form`'s method `setCyclicFocus(boolean cyclicFocus)`. Just put this value to `false`. So, use `Form.setCyclicFocus(false)`

Comment: Yes this is the stuff I was looking for and it works fab. Thanks!